# JQuery Accordion trouble adding content and aligning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day folks.  I've had some assistance from a couple of different people here at SO, so, I'm not exactly positive of everything that has been changed with my code since I began the process.  Anyways, within each of my Accordion panels, I am trying to place 4 images(logos) along with some text links above and below each logo.  I'm very new to JQuery so, I'm not sure if it is a sizing problem or what but, when I try to add to content(images) to any of the panels, everything becomes distorted.  It's hard to tell on my FIDDLE but, the actually width of the Accordion being 790px, it seems the actual "Panel 1" opens at only about half that width.  I've got two images in there now, as you can see but, if I try to add a third, the images start stacking and all the panels load opened.  Again, I am new to this so, I'm sure that it is something fairly simple that I am missing but, any new images or text that I try to add to ANY content panel results in the entire Accordion being distorted in one way or another, depending on the panel I am trying to add content.  As I said, I'm not sure if it's an alignment thing or the size of the panels or what.  People here have been gracious enough to help me out thus far and I appreciate all the assistance.  I guess this is how you learn.  Thank you for your time.

My FIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/1004/

```
CSS:
#accordion {
width:100%;
margin:10px auto;
border:1px solid black;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#accordion h2 {
clear: both;
cursor:pointer;
margin:0px 0px;
padding:7px 15px;
border:1px solid white;
background-color:#080808;
font:bold 22px Petua One;
color:#ffffff;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#accordion .content1 {
background-color:#ffffff;
padding:10px 15px;
color:black;
height:230px;
width:25%;
float:left;

}
#accordion h2.active {
background-color:#ff6600;

}

.content-wrapper{
display: inline-block;
}

.content-wrapper a{
display: block;
}

HTML:
<div id="accordion">
 <h2><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt=" photo RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png"/></a>   League Scores</h2>

<div class="content">
    <div class="content1"><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Pittsburgh Amateur<br> Hockey League</a><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png" height="100" width="100" border="0" alt=" photo PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png"/></a>

                <br><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Squirt</a><br><a href="">Pee Wee</a></div>
<div class="content1"><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">High Performance<br> Hockey League</a><br><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Association%20Logos/HPHL_zps31e66fcd.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Association%20Logos/HPHL_zps31e66fcd.png" width="90" height="90" border="0" alt=" photo HPHL_zps31e66fcd.png"/></a>
</div>
        </div>

 <h2><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt=" photo RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png"/></a>   League Standings</h2>
 <div class="content">
     <a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png" height="100" width="100" border="0" alt="Pittsburgh Amateur Hockey League - Pittsburgh, PA" title="Pittsburgh Amateur Hockey League - Pittsburgh, PA"/></a>

    <br><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Pittsburgh Amateur Hockey League</a></div>

<div class="content"></div>
 <h2><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt=" photo RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png"/></a>   Tournament Scores</h2>

<div class="content"><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/bff3d1c7-f51d-42b7-98e4-240bfe796619_zpse0bc7d8e.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/bff3d1c7-f51d-42b7-98e4-240bfe796619_zpse0bc7d8e.jpg" height="100" width="100"  border="0"  alt="OneHockey - Laguna Hills, CA" title="OneHockey - Laguna Hills, CA"/></a><br><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Minnesota Gone Wild"</a></div>
 <h2><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt=" photo RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png"/></a>   Tournament Standings</h2>

<div class="content">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/bff3d1c7-f51d-42b7-98e4-240bfe796619_zpse0bc7d8e.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/bff3d1c7-f51d-42b7-98e4-240bfe796619_zpse0bc7d8e.jpg" height="100" width="100" border="0" alt="OneHockey - Laguna Hills, CA" title="OneHockey - Laguna Hills, CA"/></a><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Minnesota Gone Wild</a>
    </div>
   <div class="content-wrapper">
    <a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Banner%20Ads/NSTESLogo_zps7c937049.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Banner%20Ads/NSTESLogo_zps7c937049.png" width="100 height="100" border="0" alt=" photo NSTESLogo_zps7c937049.png"/></a><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Blizzard Challenge</a>
```

```
JS
$(function () {
$('#accordion .content').hide();
//$('#accordion h2:first').addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
$('#accordion h2').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $('#accordion h2').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: I would suggest making your panels look the way you want them to first, without being part of the accordion. Get your HTML and CSS the way you want, then add it to the accordion.

Comment: That's a good thought @alpha.wolf  If all else fails, that's what I'll end up doing.  Trying to learn the stuff and what I'm doing wrong though.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: I've just updated your second Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/1006/ - The image in the second panel was not displayed because by accident the `<div class="content">` was missing the closing tag, instead there was an additional empty `<div class="content"></div>` at the end of the second panel.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much.  Of course, I went over it to make sure I had all the tags in there.  Missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with your css.
The fluid width of 25% applied to #accordion .content1 isn't jiving well with the static width of the #accordion .content1 img.

Comment: Thanks for the input but, I'm not exactly sure what to with it.  Should I change the width?  In this FIDDLE, I tried adding an image to the second panel and it's not showing up at all: http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/1005/

Comment: There was a missing closing quotes for the last image attribute plus a closing div for the #accordion div was missing.